# Sorting/Deleting File Lines - Python

Tags: python, string, file, line

I was wanting to get rid of lines in a file that were less than 6 characters, and delete the whole line that had a string less than 6 characters. I tried running this code, but it ended up deleting the whole text file. How would I go about this?

Code:

```
import linecache

i = 1
while i < 5:
    line = linecache.getline('file.txt', i)
    if len(line) < 6:
        str.replace(line, line, '')
    i += 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cannot reproduce this; the file is not deleted when I run your example code. Are you opening the file later in `write` mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the open method instead of the linecache:

```
def deleteShortLines():
  text = 'file.txt'
  f = open(text)
  output = []
  for line in f:
      if len(line) >= 6:
          output.append(line)
  f.close()
  f = open(text, 'w')
  f.writelines(output)
  f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Done with iterators instead of lists to support very long files:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    # iterating over a file object yields its lines one at a time
    # keep only lines with at least 6 characters 
    filtered_lines = (line for line in input_file if len(line) >= 6)

    # write the kept lines to a new file
    with open('output_file.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.writelines(filtered_lines)
```